# resolve RTF text is getting overlapping crystal report

Tags: sql-server-2012, crystal-reports-2008

I have issue in crystal report RTF data with Text overlapping right side of the field, last 2 characters are missing when i set text interpretation as RTF. if set text interpretation to "none" then its working fine. i had done setting indentation right =0.2 but no use,and can grow also true,this field is memo type.

Comment: Can you post the picture for better understanding purpose

Comment: I solved above issue by un-checking "NO Printer" option in page setup